# How to dynamically alter point radius and style of JSON path in d3?

Tags: css, json, d3.js

I need help in dynamically "highlighting" cities on a world map, created using D3 and geoJSON.

I'm working on a spinning globe with 295 city-markers on it. Every 300 millisec, one of these cities need to "be highlighted", meaning 1) change its color and 2) increase its radius (and then stay that way). This gist shows the visual so far: [gist example](http://bl.ocks.org/sara-maria/1cdfe8c7f3ccc8e46f8f400451abbc7d)

Steps taken so far:

1) I started with "circle" elements in d3: highlighting was easily done by changing their class (and using CSS styles) and radius. However: the circles remained visible on the "backside" of the globe...

2) To solve the "no circles on back of earth" problem, this post showed me that JSON paths would help: http://bl.ocks.org/PatrickStotz/1f19b3e4cb848100ffd7. 
I have now rewritten the code with these paths, and there is correct clipping of the markers on the back of the earth, but now I am stuck in dynamically accessing the radius and style of each city...

*Question about changing the radius:*
I understand that using **path.pointRadius()** I can alter the radius of the city markers. However, I want to do this dynamically (every 300msec), and only on a subselection of the markers each time. And that's where I get stuck...

*Question about changing the style:*
Also I would like to change the color, but assigning styles to the paths confuses me about how to access the JSON "Point" and "path" elements...

Code snippet showing my failed CSS styles attempt:

```
              svg.append('g')
                .selectAll("path")
                    .data(data,function(d,i){ return d.id })    
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .datum(function(d) {
                            return {
                                type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [d.lon, d.lat],
                                class: "nohighlight" //MY ATTEMPT AT CHANGING CLASS... Not working...
                            }; })
                    .attr("class","city") //this class is assigned to the "correct" paths. Can I access them individually??
                    .attr("d", pathproj);
```

Code snippet showing the time loop in which the highlighting needs to happen:

```
 //Highlighting the cities one by one:
    var city_idx = 0; //data.id starts at 1        

    //Every 300 msec: highlight a new city:
    var city_play = setInterval(function() {

                      city_idx++;

                      var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
                                          return d.id === city_idx;
                                        });  

                      // CHANGE CLASS? 
                      // CHANGE RADIUS?



                  //Stop when all cities are highlighted
                            if(city_idx>=geo_data.length){
                                            clearInterval(city_play) //terminates calls to update function within setInterval function.
                                    };
                  }, 300); // end timer city play setInterval
```

Full code in block builder:

[blockbuilder - globe and city markers](http://blockbuilder.org/sara-maria/1cdfe8c7f3ccc8e46f8f400451abbc7d)

Please do let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only. As your code uses several external files, you'll get help faster if you set up a blockbuilder or a plunker.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Will edit question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it this way:
To all path belonging to cities give a class

```
.selectAll("path")
.data(data,function(d,i){ return d.id })    
.enter()
.append("path")
.classed("city", true) <--- so all cities point will have class city
```

Next in the timer block change radius and class dynamically like this:

```
var city_play = setInterval(function() {
                        city_idx++;
                        // Control the radius of ALL circles!
                        pathproj.pointRadius(function(d,i) { 
                            //your biz logic 
                            if (i < city_idx){
                              return 4
                            } else 
                              return 2
                        });

                          // CHANGE CLASS? 
                          // CHANGE RADIUS?
                          //select all elements with class city
                            d3.selectAll(".city").attr("class", 
                            function(d, i){
                            if (i < city_idx){
                              return "city highlight"
                            } else 
                              return "city"
                          }).attr("d", pathproj)


                          var len =  d3.selectAll(".city").data().length;
                          console.log(city_idx, len)
                      //Stop when all cities are highlighted
                                if(city_idx>=len){
                                                clearInterval(city_play) //terminates calls to update function within setInterval function.
                                        };
                      }, 300);
```

working code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/c9ddb1d4076a56ad8ba91cd20c7c6781/285bfe1a18b6ff02a0135138068823f68d46de70)